# What is ES6 equivalent of module.exports = { key: "value" }?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have the following code:

```
module.exports  = { 
    key: "value",
    key2: 1234
}
```

If I change it to:

```
export default {
    key: "value",
    key2: 1234
}
```

Then the following import stops working:

```
import {key, key2} from 'module.js';
```

What is an ES6 equivalent of exporting an object?

Comment: You're exporting the object just fine, but are not importing it as an object. Use `import obj from 'module.js';` for that. If you want individual imports, you probably are not looking for an object at all - use named exports as in @MichałPerłakowski's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first define the variables and export them:

```
const key = 'value';
const key2 = 1234;

export { key, key2 };
```

Or you can export them in the same line in which you define them:

```
export const key = 'value';
export const key2 = 1234;
```

Comment: +1. This basically is the equivalent of CommonsJs/ES5 `module.exports.key = "value"; module.exports.key2 = 1234;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use export default, then you need not use the bracket. So you import the module like this:

```js
import module from 'module.js';

// access key property
console.log(module.key)
```

If you want to import your module like `import {key, key2} from 'module.js';`, refer to @Michał Perłakowski answer.

Comment: Just omitting the `default` keyword won't be enough. You can't do `export {a:1,b:2};`.